# keyup events using class instead of id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have 2 textboxes, without using id's, how do I determine which textbox is firing off "keyup" events?

For various reasons I need to use classes instead of id's, where the class name is the same for both textboxes.

Infact, I could have the same textbox on the screen many times with the same class name.

The HTML looks something like this

```
<div class="outer_div">
   <input type="text" class="mytextbox" />
   <div class="inner_div"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer_div">
   <input type="text" class="mytextbox" />
   <div class="inner_div"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer_div">
   <input type="text" class="mytextbox" />
   <div class="inner_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code (HTML & JS) please.

Comment: It's not a good idea to exclude the "id" attribute.

Comment: Why not give an id with a number at the end? like txtbox1,txtbox2??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('.mytextbox').keyup(function(event){
 // play with event
 // use $(this) to determine which element triggers this event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector by class which use with a point for example:

```
$('.foo').keyup(function(){
     $(this).attr('id');
});
```

And to determine which textbox it's fire use `$(this).attr('id')` in your event handler to get the ID of the current textbox. Also this tutorial could help you with selectors [could help you with selectors](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip10)

**UPDATE**

Adapting the code for your markup

```
$('input.mytextbox').keyup(function(){
     $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Except he doesn't have any IDs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data- attribute to assign an id eg..

```
<input data-id="x" />
```

Then do something like.

```
console.log($(this).data('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any id then you can use this keyword in the keyup function

```
$('.txtboxClass').keyup(function(event) {
   $(this) <== "This is the current textfield"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `$(".<classname>").keyUp(function (){`
      `$(this).<whatever u do here>`
        `});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this):

```
<input type="text" class="thisClass" />
<input type="text" class="thisClass" />

$(".thisClass").keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach pretend IDs onto the elements using `data()`

```
$('.foo').each(function(i,e) {
    $(e).data('fakeid', 'fakeid'+i);
});
```

Then read it back in the `keyup` event

```
$('.foo').keyup(function(){
    var fakeid = $(this).data('fakeid');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this...:)

```
<table class="table_border">
    <tbody class="container-items_items">
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" class="text-right">Cost</th>
        <th width="5%" class="text-right">Quantity</th>
        <th width="10%" class="text-right">Total</th>
        </tr> 
     <tr class="item_items">
      <td class="text-right">
        <input type="text" name="qty" class="cost_text">
      </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty_text">
      </td> 
     <td class="total_cost"></td>
    </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
         {
           $('.cost_text').on('keyup',function(e)
            {
                var cost_value = $(this).val();
                var qty_value = $(this).parents('.item_items').find('.qty_text').val();
                $(this).parents('.item_items').find('.total_cost').html(cost_value*qty_value).prepend('$');
            });

            $('.qty_text').on('keyup',function(e)
            {
                var qty_value = $(this).val();
                var cost_value = $(this).parents('.item_items').find('.cost_text').val();
                $(this).parents('.item_items').find('.total_cost').html(cost_value*qty_value).prepend('$');
            });
        })
</script>
```