# Changing input values on keyup by class name

Tags: jquery, keyup

I'm attempting to adapt an existing Jquery script which corrects the case on input values as they are being typed - previously it has run by me manually adding an onkeyup event to the input to call the script but I'd like it run based on classname instead.

I attempted to adapt the guidance given at [keyup events using class instead of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721584/keyup-events-using-class-instead-of-id) so that my script will run when the element has a class of "correctcase" but so far haven't had success in getting the script to update the value but I'm not clear on what I'm missing.

Currently I have:

```
(function($) {

    $('.correctcase').keyup(function(event){
       
        return $(this).val().replace(
            /\w\S*/g,
            function(txt) {
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            }
        );

    });

})( jQuery );
```

The previous onkeyup attribute added to the element was:

```
onkeyup="this.value=toTitleCase(this.value)"
```

So I'm sure I'm just missing something in terms of passing the value properly?

Comment: **Never** fix input values as-you-type. Just for example, move the caret a few characters and start editing / typing. Not to talk about deleting. See the issue? Instead, use the `"blur"` Event.

Comment: Also avoid the use of HTML inline `on*` attribute handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use Element.addEventListener() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Roko, the script seemed to work fine for us in terms of typing and deleting, however I have taken your advice and switched it to use the blur method instead just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your event handler you were returning the transformed value instead you needed to use it to set the value of the input element.

```js
$('.correctcase').keyup(function(event){       
  const currentValue = $(this).val();
  const transformed =
        currentValue.replace(/\w\S*/g,
          function(txt) {                
            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
          }
        );
  $(this).val(transformed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="correctcase" value="">
```

Comment: Many thanks, Diego, I understand now where I was going wrong.